# MySQL You can't specify target table X for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update, syntax-error

Any SQL gurus out there who can **rewrite the following query**:

```
UPDATE cmsTemplate 
   SET master = NULL 
 WHERE master IS NOT NULL 
   AND master NOT IN (SELECT nodeId 
                        FROM 
                           ( SELECT * FROM cmsTemplate a) b
                     )
```

So that it **does not produce the following error**:

> You can't specify target table 'cmsTemplate' for update in FROM clause

Issue documented here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Thanks,
Steve

**UPDATE: Description of query**

The idea of the query is to do as follows:

1. **SET** the *master* field **TO NULL**
2. **WHERE** the *master* field **IS NOT NULL**
3. **AND WHERE** the *master* field **IS NOT EQUAL TO ANY** of the values for the *nodeId* field records **(within the same table)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use update with join:

```
update cmsTemplate c1 left join cmsTemplate c2
on c1.`master` = c2.nodeId
set c1.`master` = null
where c2.nodeId is null;
```

Comment: Excellent! I see how it works now, thanks for the solution :)